# AppBarLayout under a toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout which contains a viewPager which allows images to be scrolled horizontally. this viewPager is located under a toolBar. The problem is that my images are cut off at the top, hidden by the toolbar.
Is it possible to position the AppBarLayout and / or the CollapsingToolbarLayout under the toolBar to obtain the complete visualization of my images. i did some testing but i can't get the result i want. any advice would be welcome. thank you in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="208dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/introSliderViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="219dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fl_wrapper" />


    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarDecouverte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorNavBarre"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

   </FrameLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/indicatorContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/introSliderViewPager" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutDecouverte"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/indicatorContainer"
    app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="150"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#FB0303"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pratique" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerDecouverte"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayoutDecouverte" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[myActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jdp.png)

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbrjy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the right method, below the result after a few tests, for me it works. you never know it can help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">


            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/introSliderViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


            </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarDecouverte"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorNavBarre"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/indicatorContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/introSliderViewPager" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutDecouverte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/indicatorContainer"
        app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="150"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FB0303"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pratique" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerDecouverte"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayoutDecouverte" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```